# Understanding behavior of memcpy() with some error examples

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, memcpy

I'm trying to write implementation of `memcpy`.
Here how it looks:

```
void *ft_memcpy(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;  
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        ((unsigned char *)s1)[i] = ((unsigned char *)s2)[i];
        i++;
    }
    return (s1);
}
```

It works mostly as string.h `memcpy`, except some error cases:

```
memcpy(NULL, NULL, 256)
```

original memcpy returns NULL, my version segfault

```
void    test_memcpy()
{
    int  array[512] = {0};
    char byte_array[512];
    memcpy(byte_array, array, sizeof(array));
}
```

Here's original memcpy ends with `zsh: abort`, my version works ok.
This cases invoke undefined behavior, but on one system/compiler I guess it should be the same, but it doesn't. Can anybody explain why it differs this way?

Comment: The C standard is not defining the behavior if the pointers are invalid.

Comment: Your version does not "work ok" in the second case. It just fails to crash in a helpful way. You are copying 2048 bytes into a 512 byte buffer. Undefined behavior is just that--undefined. It means you can't expect anything or complain about anything, or even expect that it will do the same thing twice.

Comment: Similarly my C when asked to `printf` a string which has a `NULL` pointer, kindly prints `(null)` but it doesn't have to. However there is no uniform way to deal with undefined behaviour.

Comment: `memcpy(byte_array1, array, sizeof(array));` --> `memcpy(byte_array, array, sizeof byte_array);`  `sizeof(array)`  larger than `sizeof byte_array`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO has the search. The UB was explained here billion times. IMO it is time to stop answer stupid questions. It is like: "What can happen if I close my eyes, press the pedal to the metal just before the busy crossing? Will I die, crash but survive or drive across safely?

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker Yes, and I want to understand the reason of failing to crash of my version.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 My answer is not only about UB. I have to reproduce this function with all it crashes and UB staff. Yes, maybe this question is stupid, but I couldn't find answer why my version doesn't crash in second case, although it should.

Comment: @lol_geek it has crashed the silent way. If you do what I wrote in my comment the police will arrest you for the dangerous driving even if no one was hurt. It is exactly the same. If you do not understand why writing the memory which does not belong to the object written is bad - no one can explain it to you because at the moment you have too limited knowledge of the programming. For now you need to believe that the UB is bad. When you learn more about program execution, operating systems, memory allocation etc you will understand why sometimes you will get segfault, sometimes nothing.

Comment: What is `byte_array1` in the last code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you can't predict how the program will behave.  It may crash, it may output strange results, or it may appear to work properly.  Also, a seeming unrelated change such as adding an unused variable or a call to `printf` for debugging can change the way undefined behavior manifests itself.

In the case of `test_memcpy`, `memcpy` will write past the end of `byte_array` since the size you give it is too large.  The same will happen if `ft_memcpy` is called.  Both are undefined behavior, and they need not manifest in the same way.

The same goes for passing a `NULL` pointer for the first two arguments.  `ft_memcpy` invokes undefined behavior since it attempt to dereference both pointers.  As for `memcpy`, the implementation may or may not check for `NULL` before doing anything.  Even if it doesn't, there's no guarantee it will crash.